How we convert VARCHAR2 into Clob in kafka streaming
What's the process to convert varchar2 to clob in Kafka? How is mapping performed if there is already a clob table in Oracle DB? How can a String data type be converted to a clob data type? How to map clob datatype in DB?
Mappings and logic that can help to map clob datatype in DB if there is string data type than how we convert into clob data type

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is only mapping using if statement
